# How to list AWS RDS instances with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-rds

I am trying to list all RDS instances on my Amazon account, using Ansible.

It seems that the `rds` tag can get `facts` from an instance, but not a list of instances.

I also found this: [Finding ansible RDS instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081557/finding-ansible-rds-instances), but the solution given does not work for me, as I cannot keep track of the RDS instances independently, as it would negate the point of my script.

For context, the script I'm writing is meant to list all AWS assets, like EC2 instance, RDS instance, AMIs, etc.

Comment: There's [ec2.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/690a626d0da92624235d6ef75f64c860b21b82ba/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) inventory script. Just in case...

Comment: I tried that, but that seem to only list EC2 instances, not anything else.

Comment: Try harder... there's also ec2.ini with some rds-related configs.

Comment: I've tried changing a lot of the configs, RDS related or not, and my RDS instance never shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the comments on this question, and the linked question are focusing on the EC2 module, since that module was obviously meant for EC2 management, not RDS management.

There is also an [RDS module for Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/rds_module.html). I believe to list all RDS instances you would use the following:

```
- rds:
    command: facts
```

In general however, your goal to "list all AWS assets, like EC2 instance, RDS instance, AMIs, etc." is going to run up against lots of AWS services for which there isn't a good Ansible module. Personally I like using Ansible for managing the operating system and apps running on EC2 instances as it seems Ansible is more focused on OS/application administration, and for managing AWS infrastructure something like Terraform.

For your specific case of simply listing all current resources you might want to simply write a Python script that uses Boto3 to query all the different AWS services for your various resources.

Comment: I keep getting an error when I use rds: `local variable 'resource' referenced before assignment`. I assumed it was because I couldn't call it without some sort of identifier.

Comment: It says `instance_name` is optional with `command: facts` so I assumed it would list them all. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: You ran into a failure of ansible documentation.  It happens.  All ansible documentation pages have a link to edit the docs, which will start a pull request.  You should use that and start the dialogue to fix it.  The maintainers are always busy, but they do pr review days for documentation frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because this ranks highly in search.

As of ansible 2.6, one answer is to use the [rds_instance_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/rds_instance_facts_module.html) module if you need the instance info in a playbook.

If you're using the dynamic inventory script (ec2.py), you should also have ec2.ini.  set `rds = True` (which is default in some versions).  If you don't have the stock, documented [ec2.ini](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini), it is worth getting for the documentation.